# CodeIgniter large batch insert

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, batch-file, insert

I'm currently creating a batch script that calls multiple PHP scripts (that use CodeIgniter) to pull data from one DB, work with the results and insert the result in another DB. To begin, I know this might not be the best tool for the job, but it'll have to do right now.
But back on topic, the script is running fine, and performance is pretty good, except for one method. It pulls data from the first DB, and inserts it into the second DB. It's a table that has about 20 columns and 35000 rows.

I'm using a simple `$this->db->insert_batch('tablename', $insertdata);` function to insert those results, but somehow the script takes about 15 minutes to execute...

Question is, how to optimize this process?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

Here's the query I use to create the table on the second DB, the DB that the data gets inserted into.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `invoices` (
    `invoice_number` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    `shippinglist_number` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    `shippinglist_line` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `customer_id` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `deptor` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    `vat_number` int(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `invoice_date` date NOT NULL,
    `expire_date` date NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `currency_code` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    `subtotal` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL,
    `vat` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL,
    `total` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL,
    `qty` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `partcode` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `description` text,
    `price` decimal(19,4) NOT NULL,
    `pieces_per` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `article_customer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `reference_customer` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `sales_line_1` text,
    `sales_line_2` text,
    `sales_line_3` text,
    `memo` text,
    KEY `invoice_number` (`invoice_number`,`customer_id`,`deptor`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And the query is just a normal insert, but the 35000 rows are chopped into 100 row sets.

Comment: Please post your query and the table schema.

Comment: How many indexes and key are created on your table? It should not take this much time?

Answer (score 8):

Try this

```
// some $datas

$this->db->trans_start();

$_datas = array_chunk($datas, 300);

foreach ($_datas as $key => $data) {
    $this->db->insert_batch('table', $data);
}

$this->db->trans_complete();
```

you split array. 300, 300, 300 .... (mysql recommend to insert tiny data). and insert_batch! and each 300 data  keep transaction. that is all. Sorry, I am not good at english.

Comment: Generally, it's best to include at least a minimal explanation for why the code should be the way you posted.

Comment: Sorry, I am not good at english. But I think this code is clear. you split array. 300, 300, 300 .... (mysql recommend to insert tiny data). and insert_batch! and each 300 data  keep transaction. that is all

Comment: It's not too unclear *what* the code does, but *why* it does it in precisely that way is not nearly so obvious. (Why 300? Is `array_chunck` the way it's spelled, or was there a typo? What happens if you leave out the chunking? And so forth.) And answers are valuable chiefly because they explain more than just the immediate context.

Comment: Question was how to optimize this process. I am not good at english, so I think question is how to safety insert batch data. I was looking for it, and i find this question. And fix up my code and upload my answer. Sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Use transactions - 1 commit is always faster than 350 commits.

Edit:

Basically, you need to do the following:

```
// Fetch (and transform, I suppose) data from Sybase
// ...

$this->db->trans_start();

// Put your $this->db->insert_batch() calls here

$this->db->trans_commit();
```

Comment: Will have to read into that. But don't know if one of the databases (sybase) supports that...

Comment: From what I understand - you're only fetching data from Sybase. Transactions are only useful with write-type queries, so Sybase doesn't concern you.

Comment: Okay, well as I said, don't really know to much about Transactions, so will have to google a bit ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$x = $this->db->num_rows();
for($i=0;$i<$x;$i=$i+30)
    {
    $this->db//query stuff
    $this->db->limit($i);
    $other->db->//insert stuff
    }
```

That way you do it line by line and you are not dependant on one huge sql query.
That way you could restart whenver you wanted if some error or timeout had occurred.

Are the databases on the same server? Then you could just use a query to copy the data with a select from other database(if the same user has access to both)

Comment: Databases are not on the same server, and one server doesn't support limit, so I can't limit the select query, but the codeigniter `insert_batch` function chops the query up in batches of 100 itself, so it's kinda doing what you say.

Comment: Well, 15 minutes is then what you can expect with 35000 rows with a select running on one end, and an insert at the other end.
The only way you could optimize is to see if values have changed/remember the last index, and only update the newer fields that were inserted into the database.
But that only works if this isn't a backup. If it's for a backup you'll need the entire table with all it's contents.
Maybe use a faster network connection and more processing power assigned to php & sql  on the server you're executing?

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, however for those who landed here while searching for an answer to this may be this link may help you.

$this->db->save_queries = FALSE;

http://greeneggmedia.com/blog/entry/undocumented-codeigniter

In the background CI try to save queries for profiling, if you disable this feature you can gain lot of time.

If you dont like this answer please dont downvote. was just trying to help.